# How to add ranges for arguments in C++

Tags: c++

the exercise was to write a program that displays on the screen
table of functions
`a*x*x+b*x+c`

The argument changes in the range -10..10

- a - random number in the range 1..5
- b - random number in the range -7..7
- c - random number in the range -10..10

Complete the task three times, displaying all of them
results of performed calculations

The screen may look like this:

```
            a1=... a2=... a3=...
            b1=... b2=... b3=...
            c1=... c2=... c3=...

argument array1 array2 array3
-------------------------------------------------- ----
-10 score1(-10) score2(-10) score3(-10)
-9 score1(-9) score2(-9) score3(-9)
-8 score1(-8) score2(-8) score3(-8)
-7 score1(-7) score2(-7) score3(-7)
. . .
10 score1(+10) score2(+10) score3(+10)
```

The code I've written with no result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string tablicowanie1, tablicowanie2, tablicowanie3;
    int a, b, c, x;
    cout << "Tablicowanie funkcji";
        cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Program wyswietla tablicowanie funkcji a*x*x+b*x+c: ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    
    vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector<int> b = {-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    vector<int> c = { -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    vector<int> x = { -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        

    cout << "a1 = ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "b1 = ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "c1 = ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "x1 = ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << tablicowanie1 << "Wynik tablicowania1: ";
    cout << a * x * x + b * x + c;
    cout << endl << endl;
```

I've tried vector and range, expected to draw random number from the range for a, b, c and x

Comment: `int a,b,c,x;` and `vector<int> a,b,c,d;` can't be in the same scope.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i don't think you have a basic idea of what the exercise wants - back to your book! also, going forward, always program in english.